# dynamic text inputs save to the db via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['fields'] as $fieldIndex => $fieldValue) {
    $stmt = $dbconnect->prepare('INSERT INTO  '); <<=== How to insert values  
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    $(".left .inputs").append("<li><input type ='text' name='fields[]' class='txtbox1'></li>");
    $(".right .inputs").append("<li><input type ='text' name='fields[]' class='txtbox'></li>");
});
```

I want to save dynamic values to the database. u used above codes. Jquery will pass the value and I'm fetching it using foreach. But I don't know how will I insert values to the database.I have two column in the table, like user one, user two. But how I add dynamic data to each new row?

Comment: the column names are known or dynamic?

Comment: I now column names.In create table sql i created that 2 column

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$fieldssend = $_POST['fields']; //an array of fields
```

you can then access each field using $fieldssend[0] and $fieldssend[1]

```
$stmt = $dbconnect->prepare('INSERT INTO ... values $fieldssend[0], $fieldssend[1] '); 
$stmt->execute();
```

just put the correct syntax for your case.

Comment: 'INSERT INTO ... values $fieldssend[0], $fieldssend[1] ' if we have values more than 2 how to use this ? this is wrong

Comment: you talked about 2 columns of the table. and your jquery shows 2 variables. make your question more clear.